# Hover dropdown menu not working using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a drop down menu that I made, but it's not working...the target element must be incorrect but I can't figure it out..please help

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/b399yokj/1/)**

you need to apply the changes on the dropdown ul ( second ul ) not on the `li` or the `a` that are in it.

instead of `ul li li a` use this CSS code :

```
 ul  ul{
        display: none;
    }
```

and JQ :

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('.myli').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();

    });


});
```

**ALSO** you could use only CSS to do this. BUT if you want to replicate the `slideToggle` transition you should know that `transition` in css works only with 'calculable' values (0,1,100%) etc. so it doesn't work with `display` or `visibility` so in order to do this you need to know the fixed height of the dropdown and do it like so

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/b399yokj/3/)**

```
ul  ul{
   transition:0.5s;
   max-height: 0;
   overflow:hidden;
    }

 ul li.myli:hover > ul { 
   max-height: 300px;
 }
```

Comment: glad i could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution...

You can simply do with css only...

```
.myli {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 180px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}
.myli:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

<li class="myli"><a href="#">Home</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove this part on line 45:
        ul li li a {
            display: none;
        }

and add this:

```
    ul li ul {
        display: none;
    }

    ul li:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }
```